# Does Spark.ml LogisticRegression assumes numerical features only?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml, apache-spark-mllib

I was looking at the `Spark 1.5` [dataframe/row api](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row) and the [implementation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.5/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/LogisticRegression.scala) for the logistic regression. As I understand, the `train` method therein first converts the `dataframe` to `RDD[LabeledPoint]` as,

```
override protected def train(dataset: DataFrame): LogisticRegressionModel = {
     // Extract columns from data.  If dataset is persisted, do not persist oldDataset.
     val instances = extractLabeledPoints(dataset).map {
           case LabeledPoint(label: Double, features: Vector) => (label, features)
     }
...
```

And then it proceeds to feature standardization, etc.

What I am confused with is, the `DataFrame` is of type `RDD[Row]` and `Row` is allowed to have any `valueTypes`, for e.g. `(1, true, "a string", null)` seems a valid row of a dataframe. If that is so, what does the `extractLabeledPoints` above mean? It seems it is selecting only `Array[Double]` as the feature values in `Vector`. What happens if a column in the data-frame was `strings`? Also, what happens to the integer categorical values?

Thanks in advance,
Nikhil

Comment: Categorical values before being passed to MLlib / ML estimators have to be encoded as `Double`. There quite a few built-in transformers like [`StringIndexer`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#stringindexer) or [`OneHotEncoder`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#onehotencoder) which can be helpful here. 

If algorithm treats categorical features in a different manner than a numerical ones, like for example `DecisionTree`, you identify which variables are categorical using `categoricalFeaturesInfo`.

Comment: Finally some transformers use special attributes on columns to distinguish between different types of attributes.

Comment: @zero323 I think these two answers from you beg for being the accepted answer. Mind answering (not commenting)?

Comment: @zero323, So it seems the onus is assumed on the user to adjust the data frames before processing. Makes sense, since there is no way ad-hoc to know if some variable is categorical or not (especially in case of integer class labels). Just that it is not clear from their API. 

In one place they show an example of Row with `Any` valueType columns and other places they just say `train(dataset)`

Comment: @NikhilJJoshi It is possible, and some tools from ML can handle that for you, but it is not something that should be done implicitly.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I couldn't decide if mark it as a duplicate. There are quite a few similar questions already.

Answer (score 5):

Lets ignore Spark for a moment. Generally speaking linear models, including logistic regression, expect numeric independent variables. It is not in any way specific to Spark / MLlib. If input contains categorical or ordinal variables these have to be encoded first. Some languages, like R, handle this in a transparent manner:

```
> df <- data.frame(x1 = c("a", "b",  "c", "d"), y=c("aa", "aa", "bb", "bb"))
> glm(y ~ x1, df, family="binomial")

Call:  glm(formula = y ~ x1, family = "binomial", data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          x1b          x1c          x1d  
 -2.357e+01   -4.974e-15    4.713e+01    4.713e+01  
...
```

but what is really used behind the scenes is so called design matrix:

```
> model.matrix( ~ x1, df)
  (Intercept) x1b x1c x1d
1           1   0   0   0
2           1   1   0   0
3           1   0   1   0
4           1   0   0   1
...
```

Skipping over the details it is the same type of transformation as the one performed by the `OneHotEncoder` in Spark.

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{OneHotEncoder, StringIndexer}

val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
    Tuple1("a"), Tuple1("b"), Tuple1("c"), Tuple1("d")
)).toDF("x").repartition(1)

val indexer = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("x")
  .setOutputCol("xIdx")
  .fit(df)

val indexed = indexer.transform(df)

val encoder = new OneHotEncoder()
    .setInputCol("xIdx")
    .setOutputCol("xVec")

val encoded = encoder.transform(indexed)

encoded
    .select($"xVec")
    .map(_.getAs[Vector]("xVec").toDense)
    .foreach(println)
```

Spark goes one step further and all features, even if algorithm allows nominal/ordinal independent variables, have to be stored as `Double` using a `spark.mllib.linalg.Vector`. In case of `spark.ml` it is a `DataFrame` column, in `spark.mllib` a field in `spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint`.

Depending on a model interpretation of the feature vector can be different though. As mentioned above for linear model these will be interpreted as numerical variables. For `Naive Bayes` theses are considered nominal. If model accepts both numerical and nominal variables Spark and treats each group in a different way, like decision / regression trees, you can provide [`categoricalFeaturesInfo`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-decision-tree.html#problem-specification-parameters) parameter.

It is worth pointing out that dependent variables should be encoded as `Double` as well but, unlike independent variables, may require additional metadata to be handled properly. If you take a look at the `indexed` DataFrame you'll see that `StringIndexer` not only transforms `x`, but also adds attributes:

```
scala> org.apache.spark.ml.attribute.Attribute.fromStructField(indexed.schema(1))
res12: org.apache.spark.ml.attribute.Attribute = {"vals":["d","a","b","c"],"type":"nominal","name":"xIdx"}
```

Finally some `Transformers` from `ML`, like [VectorIndexer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#vectorindexer), can automatically detect and encode categorical variables based on the number of distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

**Copying clarification from zero323 in the comments:**

Categorical values before being passed to MLlib / ML estimators have to be encoded as `Double`. There quite a few built-in transformers like `StringIndexer` or `OneHotEncoder` which can be helpful here. If algorithm treats categorical features in a different manner than a numerical ones, like for example `DecisionTree`, you identify which variables are categorical using `categoricalFeaturesInfo`.

Finally some transformers use special attributes on columns to distinguish between different types of attributes.